# Constraints on many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, many-to-many

I have a multi-user task tracker. Users are in table `user`:

```
+---------------+---------+
|user_id(int,PK)|name(str)|
+---------------+---------+
|1              |Alice    |
|2              |Bob      |
+---------------+---------+
```

Tasks are in table `task`:

```
+---------------+----------------+---------+
|task_id(int,PK)|group_id(int,FK)|name(str)|
+---------------+----------------+---------+
|1              |1 (Shared)      |Dishes   |
|2              |2 (Personal)    |Exercise |
+---------------+----------------+---------+
```

Tasks belong to groups. Groups are in table `group`:

```
+----------------+----------------+
|group_id(int,PK)|name(str)       |
+----------------+----------------+
|1               |Shared Household|
|2               |Personal-Bob\'s |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Users are linked with groups in a many-to-many relationship.
Table `link_user_group`:

```
+------------------+-------------------+
|user_id(int,PK,FK)|group_id(int,PK,FK)|
+------------------+-------------------+
|1 (Alice)         |1 (Shared)         |
|2 (Bob)           |1 (Shared)         |
|2 (Bob)           |2 (Personal)       |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

When a task is done, a tick is recorded in table `tick`:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|tick_id(int,PK)|user_id(int,FK)|task_id(int,FK)|tick_date(date)|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|1              |1 (Alice)      |1 (Dishes)     |2021-09-23     |
|2              |2 (Bob)        |1 (Dishes)     |2021-09-25     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Whole database:
[image: Diagram of database]

How do I create a constraint to prevent inserting `user_id=1 (Alice), task_id=2 (Exercise)` into `tick`?

I have a helper view `link_user_task`:

```
SELECT `user_id`,`task_id`
FROM `task`
LEFT JOIN `group` USING(`group_id`)
CROSS JOIN `link_user_group` USING (`group_id`);
+------------+------------+
|user_id(int)|task_id(int)|
+------------+------------+
|1 (Alice)   |1 (Dishes)  |
|2 (Bob)     |1 (Dishes)  |
|2 (Bob)     |2 (Exercise)|
+------------+------------+
```

When I want to insert a new tick, I call the stored procedure `insert_tick(i_chore_id,i_user_id,i_tick_date)`:

```
INSERT INTO `ticks` (`user_id`,`task_id`,`tick_date`)
SELECT `user_id`,`task_id`,i_tick_date AS `tick_date`
FROM `link_user_task`
WHERE user_id` = i_user_id AND `task_id` = i_task_id
LIMIT 1
```

This ensures that the tick is entered only if the valid user/task combination is entered.

I am considering writing a trigger in case a user is removed from a group. Removing Bob from shared household removes Bob's ticks of dishes.

Is there a way to define these constraints using foreign keys instead?

Comment: The scheme is wrong. `task` must rely not to `group` but to `link_user_group` as many-to-many (adjacent table). And tick must rely to this relation (1:1 or 1:N to this adjacent table).

Comment: Database "constraints" have limited capabilities.  A complex constraint should be coded in the application.

Comment: An insert trigger can enforce that constraint, so that no client can insert an invalid "tick".  Also, I wouldn't physically remove records from the user-group relation, but rather flag them as "deactivated", which the trigger may take into account. Bod did do the dishes once, it would be a pity to forget that.

Comment: @Akina The `link_user_group` has a composite primary key, consisting of both columns `user_id` and `group_id`. A single `group_id` occurs on multiple rows if more than one user are in that group.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Can you write an answer explaining that trigger? Should I run the trigger post-insert to clean up all invalid rows?

Comment: The example in my question is simplified. In reality, there is another 1:N layer between tasks and groups (group has categories, category has tasks). Category is something like "Cleaning" or "Cats". How should my foreign keys be arranged?

Comment: "Should I run the trigger" ?  You may need to learn about database triggers. I had a pre-insert trigger in mind that would prevent inserting invalid data. Again: I wouldn't delete information.